# Stored proc date filtering causing no records to be returned

Tags: t-sql

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetErrorsByDate]
(
    @p_skip INT
   ,@p_take INT
   ,@p_orderBy VARCHAR(50) = 'TimestampDesc'
   ,@p_startDate SMALLDATETIME = NULL
   ,@p_endDate SMALLDATETIME = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

    WITH pathAuditErrorLogCT AS
    (
        SELECT
          CASE
            WHEN @p_orderBy = 'TimestampAsc' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E.[Timestamp])
            WHEN @p_orderBy = 'TimestampDesc' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E.[Timestamp] DESC)                                         
            WHEN @p_orderBy = 'LogIdAsc' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E.LogId)
            WHEN @p_orderBy = 'LogIdDesc' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E.LogId DESC)                                 
            WHEN @p_orderBy = 'ReferrerUrlAsc' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E.ReferrerUrl)
            WHEN @p_orderBy = 'ReferrerUrlDesc' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E.ReferrerUrl DESC)                                    
          END AS RowNum
          ,E.Id
        FROM pathAuditErrorLog AS E   
        WHERE
          (E.[Timestamp] >= @p_startDate OR @p_startDate IS NULL)
        AND
          (E.[Timestamp] <= @p_endDate OR @p_endDate IS NULL)                     
    )                   
    SELECT
      E.Id
     ,E.Node
     ,E.HttpCode
     ,E.[Timestamp]
     ,E.[Version]
     ,E.LogID
     ,E.IsFrontEnd
     ,E.ReferrerUrl
     ,E.[Login]
     ,E.BrowserName
     ,E.BrowserVersion
     ,E.ErrorDetails
     ,E.ServerVariables
     ,E.StackTrace
    FROM pathAuditErrorLog AS E

    INNER JOIN pathAuditErrorLogCT AS pct ON pct.Id = E.Id

    WHERE pct.RowNum BETWEEN @p_skip + 1 AND (@p_skip + @p_take)

    ORDER BY RowNum
END
```

The idea is that the procedure returns data from an error table, but allows dynamic column ordering, paging and date filtering. My problem is the date filtering that's part of the common table expression. I'm having trouble getting this to work.

If I remove the date filtering logic then the proc works fine. With it included, then I often get no rows returned even though there were rows expected. For example if I try:

```
exec GetErrorsByDate 0, 10, 'TimestampDesc', '2013-02-05'
```

Giving only the start date, then I get a bunch of records backs. However, if I do this:

```
exec GetErrorsByDate 0, 10, 'TimestampDesc', '2013-02-05', '2013-02-05'
```

Passing both a start and end date, I end up with no records returned. This is odd since I expected some of the records from the first query to appear in the second.

Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong please?

EDIT:
I've applied what AdaTheDev has suggested and it looks closer to what I need. However I have found one case where the suggested method does not return what I expected. If I run the following:

```
exec GetErrorsByDate 0, 10, 'TimestampDesc', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-03'
```

I get one row whose timestamp is `2013-01-02 13:29:00`. If I run this:

```
exec GetErrorsByDate 0, 10, 'TimestampDesc', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02'
```

I get no rows returned. I was hoping to see the one row from the previous query to be returned, since it's timestamp does fall on the 2nd of Jan 2013. Have I misunderstood something here?

Comment: In your where clause you are using e in small case and you have given uppercase as alias to the table

Comment: Cheers, I've fixed the typo, missed it initially. Though that won't fix the issue I'm experiencing mind.

Answer (score 2):

That will only return records where the `Timestamp` is exactly 2013-02-05 (i.e. midnight), so records during that day will not be included (I'm assuming they all have times associated).

If you want to include them I would change the clause to:

```
WHERE
          (e.[Timestamp] >= @p_startDate OR @p_startDate IS NULL)
        AND
          (e.[Timestamp] < @p_endDate OR @p_endDate IS NULL)
```

(change is the @p_enddate clause is now just `<`)

And then do:

```
exec GetErrorsByDate 0, 10, 'TimestampDesc', '2013-02-05', '2013-02-06'
```

Comment: Ahh OK. Do I need to worry about using the DATEADD DATEDIFF technique for removing the time portion? What you state makes sense, I'm taking the time into the equation which is causing a problem.

Comment: You *could* use a technique like that *but* you should avoid doing so - using functions like that in your WHERE clause will make the query non-sargable - i.e. if there is a suitable index in place on the Timestamp column, it would prevent the index being used and therefore impacts performance. So, best to stick with the approach above.